Azure DevOps web extension for custom repo picker - how to add an input form
I am trying to build a custom web extension in Azure DevOps, with which i can initialize a repository with some files bootstrapped. I want to present a form to the user to get some input and then based on that input i want to initialise the repository with a file , filled based on the inputs. For example a form like below:

I am aware that we can use - ms.vss-code-web.command-bar-repository-picker-actions for adding a button to initialise custom repository.
I was trying to use custom panel from package azure-devops-ui/Panel as per below:
const panelSvc = await SDK.getService<IHostPageLayoutService>(CommonServiceIds.HostPageLayoutService);
            panelSvc.openPanel<string | undefined>("New Managed Repository", {
                description: "Provide the required Input to initialize a managed repository.",
                onClose: () => console.log("Panel closed"),
                configuration: {
               
                    onclose: {handleClose}, onCreate: { handleCreate }
                }
            });

But i am not able to proceed further, As IPanelOptions interface doesnt have any property to embed a form in the panel.
